# Vim: strange behavior of "\" in insert mode

Tags: vim, keymap

I'm editing a lot of tex files using vim, and therefore I use the `\` character a lot.
Yet, when inserting a `\` in insert mode, vim pauses the cursor on the same spot for one second, unlike with any other character.

Of course I don't have to physically wait for one whole second, I can just keep on typing, yet the text is only inserted after this second.

I found that I can create similar behavior by mapping e.g.:

```
inoremap ;; <esc>:
inoremap jj <esc>
```

etc. It seems as if vim is expecting another character to follow, so it can evaluate the map.

Unsetting `\` as the mapleader doesn't alleviate the problem though, which is what I expected.

Also, I don't know if this is related, but using `<esc>` in insert mode doesn't work instantly (again because vim expects something to come after).

Is there a vim setting that let's me put the paste time to 0, yet I still want to be allowed to use my mappings `;;`, `jj` and `<esc>`.

I know about `timeout` yet this doesn't help. If I do `timeoutlen=0` none of the multi-key mappings would be useable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've identified the problem: \ is being used as the first character of an imap. To find out where it is being set you can execute

```
:verbose imap \
```

I don't have any solution other than to eliminate the mapping or unmap it when you're editing TeX files. You can do that by putting a line like this in a file named ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim on Unix or ~\vimfiles\after\ftplugin\tex.vim on Windows:

```
silent! iunmap \x
```

where you would replace `x` by the corresponding part of the offending mapping.

I use LaTeX a little, have the Vim-LaTeX-Suite installed, and do not see that behavior, so at least it's not a problem with that suite.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an insert mode mapping starting with "\", possibly set by a plugin you have recently installed.  To find if you do, and what file created the mapping(s), run this command:

```
:verbose imap \
```