# xml.vim corrupts '\' paste

Tags: vim, copy-paste, vim-plugins

I am using vim on Linux.  I have xml.vim plugin loaded.  If I do a paste of a string like "\." what I get is ">".  If I do an insert, and pause, I can type "\."  Apparently this is due to insert mode mapping".  I edit xml, and like the plugin - has anyone addressed this problem?

Comment: I got some background from http://superuser.com/questions/354545/vim-strange-behavior-of-in-insert-mode but it provides no presecriptive solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim's `paste` mode disables features that can interfere with pasting, such as mappings and indentation. Simply `:set paste` before pasting and `:set nopaste` when you're done.

Because `paste` disables mappings in Insert mode, you can't use regular mappings to toggle it, but you can use the `pastetoggle` option instead. For example, to define <kbd>F9</kbd> as a toggle key:

```
:set pastetoggle=<F9>
```

Comment: Thanks Bradd!  Solves my problem.  I used :set pt=<f9> as recommended by http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6122/vims-pastetoggle-when-you-press-f9-paste-is-on-press-f9-again-and-paste-is-off-and-so-forth-works-in-insert-mode-and-command-mode as a working fix.

Comment: Thanks for posting the link: `pastetoggle` is easier to use than I thought. The extra example in the Vim docs confused me. I'll update my answer with the simple usage.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't?! When you have `:imap`s starting with `\`, and you have identified them, either avoid their definition (if the plugin allows to configure a different mapping or to turn off mappings), or `:iunmap` the offending mapping. When the problem only occurs for the `xml` filetype, the place for that would be `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/xml.vim`.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I don't quite have the time to explore the situation right now, and so am choosing the 'pastetoggle' solution suggested above.